# How to check if session exists globally. Using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication

Currently I am using Codeigniter library for my project and have a custom CMS made. Which obviously password protected but before loading every controller I have a function which I run to check if session exists and admin login otherwise redirect to login page.

```
public function checkLoginStatus(){

    if($this->session->userdata('is_admin_login') != true) {

    redirect(base_url().'admin/');

    }

}
```

Is there a way I can check this globally and don't have to load in every controller?

Answer (score 0):

my solution is.

```
if(empty($this->session->userdata('is_admin_login') ) {
    redirect(base_url().'login/');
    }else{
  redirect(base_url().'admin/');
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. My function is working too but the question is how to use it globally so I don't have to use it in every controller file